# Android - Prioritization in RealmResult

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

Is it possible to add a filter like prioritization in RealmResult
ex.

```
RealmResult<Persons> persons
Id | Name
1   Eleo
2   Cath
8   Chris
9   Emman
5   John
```

I want to prioritize "John" then "Emman" then sort by "Id"

```
RealmResult<Persons> persons
Id | Name
5   John
9   Emman
1   Eleo
2   Cath
8   Chris
```

Is it possible to achieve this kind of sorting?

```
RealResult <Persons> persons_list = realm.where(Persons.class).findAll().sort("id").priority("id",int[]{5,9});
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. You can sort on multiple fields though, so if you can assign your priorities an int-value you can create a priority field and sort using `findAllSorted("priority", Sort.ASC, "id", Sort.ASC)`

Comment: Uereka! thanks for the comment now I have an Idea. .Ill post an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I got an Idea mention by @Christian
maybe I'll create a column that contains index. .that default is null
and if I want to prioritize I have to get the non null and increment the result
and set it as index

example

```
Id | Name | Index
5   John   (null)
9   Emman  (null)
1   Eleo   (null)
2   Cath   (null)
8   Chris  (null)

int get_non_null_index = realm.where(Persons.class).isNotNull("Index").findAll().size();
get_non_null_index += 1
john.setIndex(get_non_null_index);
get_non_null_index += 1
emmain.setIndex(get_non_null_index);
```

findAllSorted("Index", Sort.DESC)